# How to resize a table with xlwings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwings

I am trying to figure out how to resize a table using xlwings but can't figure out how.

I have tried using the `resize(range)` property but I am getting getting the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'api'
```

This is the code I got the error with :

```
import xlwings as xw

tableau = xw.books['test_book.xlsx'].sheets[0].tables[0]

tableau.resize('<Range [test_book.xlsx]Feuil1!$A$1:$B$6>')
```

I tried different values for the range attribut like `$A$1:$B$6` or `A1:B6` but still couldn't make it work.

So how can I manage to resize my table using xlwings ?

Comment: `resize` accepts an xlwings range as the argument, e.g., `xw.books[...].sheets[0].range('A1:B2')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't need to, the table is resized automatically.
This is the code I ran for your previous question using an Excel file with a table, 'Table1' consisting of 3 columns and 3 rows with header row so the table range is A1:C4. The code adds two additional rows as individual cells and as a tuple. As each row is added the size of the table increases to the include the added rows.

```
import xlwings as xw

workbook = 'table1.xlsx'

wb = xw.Book(workbook)
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

print("Original Table")
table = ws.cells.table
print("Table Range: " + str(table.range.address))

# Added data by cell
ws.range('A5').value = '444'
ws.range('B5').value = '333'
ws.range('C5').value = '222'
table2 = ws.cells.table
print("Table Range after 1 row added: " + str(table2.range.address))

### Added row
ws['A6'].value = [111, 999, 987]
table3 = ws.cells.table
print("Table Range after 2nd row added: " + str(table3.range.address))

wb.save(workbook)
wb.close()
```

Ouput

```
Original Table  
Table Range: $A$1:$C$4

Added rows  
Table Range after 1 row added: $A$1:$C$5  
Table Range after 2nd row added: $A$1:$C$6
```